# Problem in server and client application for testing IBM-MQ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ibm-mq

I have two applications for the testing of the MQ events. One of them is used to send messages and another one is used to receive messages. Both of them are SpringBoot applications.
The sender app is running on `port: 8000` and receiver app is running on  `port: 8050`
**pom.xml**

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the sender application.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
@RestController
public class MqTestApplication {

    private static final String ISSUER = "254874125487";
    private static final String ACCOUNT_NO = "1234567890123";

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MqTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    public Event getEvent() {
        Event event = new Event();
        Map<String, Object> argument = new HashMap<>();
        argument.put("key-accNo", ACCOUNT_NO);
        event.setMessageId(String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()));
        event.setIssuer(ISSUER);
        event.setType(EventType.ACCOUNT);
        event.setName(EventName.OPEN_ACCOUNT);
        event.setArgument(argument);
        event.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        return event;
    }

    @GetMapping("send/event")
    public void sendEvent() {
        try {
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("DESTINATION", getEvent());
        } catch (JmsException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Receiver Application**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableJms
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

}
```

```java
@Service
public class MQServiceImpl{

    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    public MQServiceImpl(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "DESTINATION")
    public void receiveEvent() {
        Event event = (Event) jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert("DESTINATION");
        System.out.println(event.toString());
    }    
}
```

But when I run the receiver application, I face with below exception rapidly and continuously.

```
DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] WARN  o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void .service.MQServiceImpl.receiveEvent()' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.MessageFormatException: JMSCC0053: An exception occurred deserializing a message, exception: 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null class'.; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageFormatException: JMSCC0053: An exception occurred deserializing a message, exception: 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null class'.
It was not possible to deserialize the message because of the exception shown.
Examine the linked exception for details of the error.

Caused by: org.springframework.jms.MessageFormatException: JMSCC0053: An exception occurred deserializing a message, exception: 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null class'.; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageFormatException: JMSCC0053: An exception occurred deserializing a message, exception: 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null class'.
It was not possible to deserialize the message because of the exception shown.
Examine the linked exception for details of the error.
```

I searched the log but none of those answers helped me. I appreciate it if anybody has an idea to solve this problem.

**Update**

In both sender and receiver applications, the event class is like this.

```java
@Data
public class Event implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2529600986924604571L;

    private String messageId;
    private String issuer;
    private EventType type;
    private EventName name;
    private Map<String, Object> argument;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the `@JmsListener` annotation does?

Comment: @M. Deinum The `@JmsListener` annotation marks a method to listen as a JMS message listener. Right?

Comment: Are the messages being read serialized java objects?

Comment: @JoshMc If I call `receiveEvent()` in `MqTestApplication` I can read the `Event` object that is sent with method `sendEvent()` , but the problem is when I want to start the receiver application. I don't have any idea.

Comment: It marks the method as a listener, so why receive the message yourself? You are getting a trigger and then receive the message again, that is not going to work. Just add a method argument to your `receiveEvent` method of type `Event`.

Comment: @M. Deinum I did it as you said, again it gives me this error
```org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void service.MQServiceImpl.receiveEvent(mq.dto.Event)' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not convert JMS message; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageFormatException: JMSCC0053: An exception occurred deserializing a message, exception: 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null class'.
It was not possible to deserialize the message```

Comment: You ofcourse need to remove the `jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert` line and make sure all your related objects are `Serializable` as well.

Comment: yes, I removed `jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert` too and the Event class implements Serializable as in the questions but nothing change.

Comment: @M. Deinum I posted the answer. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days, I found out the answer. I should convert the Event object to the JSON and then send it from the sender application and receive the JSON from the sender and convert it to the Event object. Actually, we can't send or receive the objects through MQ directly.

**Sender**

```java
  String stringEvent = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(EVENT_OBJ);
  jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(SEND_QUEUE_NAME, stringEvent);
```

**Receiver**

```java
  @Override
    @JmsListener(destination = "${mq.receive_queue}")
    public void receive(Message message) {
        try {
            String jsonEvent = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
            Event event = objectMapper.readValue(jsonEvent, Event.class);
        } catch (JMSException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to send JSON then just set the appropriate `MessageConverter` to the `JmsTemplate`, that way the `JmsTemplate` handles that for you instead of you doing it manually.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As has been hinted in the comments your `Event` class needs to be serialisable, which it does seem to be and the listener code should look something like:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "DESTINATION")
public void receiveEvent(Event event) {
   ...
```

Spring will take care of serialising the object as part of the `@JmsListener` annotation.

Although hard-coding a destination is not good, and you should be pulling it from application.properties.

> Update If you are still getting a `ClassNotFoundException` then the
> serialisation that is being triggered is unable to find the classes.
> If your code is compiling then you probably have a class `Event` in
> your class path, but for some reason it isn't being recognised as
> compatible with the object that the receiving app is expecting.

On the surface it looks as though you have the `Event` object right, but that class, with the same properties and same `serialVersionUID` needs to be present in both sender and receiver code. If you make a changed in one, that must be present in the other. The easiest way to force this is is to put the class into a `.jar` that is used by both applications. If you have `Event` class is in different packages for sender and receiver, then it will be considered a different class.

If you add the `@data` annotation, spring will take care of a lot of the serialisation boiler-plate for you. EG.

```java
import lombok.Data;

@Data 
public class Event implements Serializable {    
   ...
```

If that still doesn't work, then you can opt to receive an `ObjectMessage` and perform the serialisation yourself. You might find out why the spring automated serialisation fails.

EG.

```java
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage; 
import java.io.Serializable;

@JmsListener(destination = "DESTINATION") 
public void receiveEvent(ObjectMessage message) {    
   Serializable serObj = message.getObject();    
   try {
      Event event = (Event) serObj;
      ...    
   } catch (ClassCastException e) {
      ...    
   }    
   ...
```

Comment: I did it as you said, but again it gives me this error.
```org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void service.MQServiceImpl.receiveEvent(mq.dto.Event)' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not convert JMS message; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageFormatException: JMSCC0053: An exception occurred deserializing a message, exception: 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null class'.
It was not possible to deserialize the message```

Comment: That implies that the class with `public class Event implements Serializable` or one of its dependencies is not in the class path.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution but unfortunately still have the same error. It's weird, If I test to receive the message in the sender application it works but when I want to receive from the receiver application I face with this exception.

Comment: Please read my updated answer - Your error implies that the Event class in the receiving app is different to the Event class in the sending app.

Comment: Of course, I read your answer. The class `Event` in both apps is the same except package name. I update question.

Comment: I think they would need to be in the same package.

Comment: I posted the answer. Thanks for your guidance.